Spring Boot auth-service unable to connect to PostgreSQL server
I'm developing a Spring Boot application that includes an auth-service module. The auth-service is configured to connect to a PostgreSQL database, but I'm encountering an issue where the application is unable to establish the connection.
Here is the application.yml file for the auth-service:
yaml
Copy code
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${SPRING_DATASOURCE_HOST:postgres}:5432/${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB:emergency_db}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:admin}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:admin911}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${SPRING_DATASOURCE_HOST:postgres}:5432/${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB:emergency_db}
    user: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:admin}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:admin911}
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    enabled: true
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    validate-on-migrate: false

And here is the relevant excerpt from the Docker Compose file:
yaml
Copy code
services:
  auth-service:
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_HOST: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB: emergency_db
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: admin911
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: emergency_db
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin911

When I try to start the auth-service, it fails to connect to the PostgreSQL server and throws the following error:

vbnet org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path
resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]:
Unable to obtain connection from database: The connection attempt
failed.

The error message indicates that the auth-service is unable to connect to the PostgreSQL server at postgres:5432.
What I've tried:
Verified the PostgreSQL connection details in the application.yml file are correct.
Checked the PostgreSQL server status and confirmed it's running and accepting connections.
Tested the PostgreSQL connection using a client tool like psql and was able to connect successfully.
Inspected the Docker Compose logs for any network or DNS-related issues, but didn't find any.
Tried using the PostgreSQL server's IP address instead of the postgres hostname in the application.yml file, but the issue persisted.
Expected behavior:
The auth-service should be able to successfully connect to the PostgreSQL server and perform its database operations.
Actual behavior:
The auth-service is unable to connect to the PostgreSQL server, and the application fails to start.

The auth service itself is not the component with the connection problem; flyway - a database migration tool - can't connect. Check the flyway configuration. You'll need something like flyway.url=postgresql://postgres/emergency_db?user=admin&password=admin911


    If you are using a recent version of PostgreSQL, this issue might be occurring due to a timezone mismatch. The timezone of the request machine and the PostgreSQL server may be different. I suggest checking the timezone settings in PostgreSQL to see if they differ from your system's timezone. You can either alter the timezone in the database or adjust your machine's settings accordingly.
Below is a sample query you can use to check the current timezone in PostgreSQL:
Query to check the time zone in the PGAdmin
 SHOW timezone;

Alter the timezone in PGAdmin
ALTER DATABASE your_database SET timezone TO 'your_timezone';

I thought it might be helpful.
